# Different bases of symmetric polynomials

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

Let the symmetric group $S_n$ act on $R^n$ by permuting coordinates and consider the ring of symmetric polynoials. These symmetric polynomials can be written fro example as polynomials in the elementary symmetric polynomials. However, there are many other examples of generators one might pick: Any set of $n$ algebraically independent symmetric polynomials with the degrees $(1,\ldots,n)$. Is there any nice way of realting the different basis polynomials with the hyperplane arrangement associated to the action of $S_n$?